# Alarm playing with audio in the background Irregular?

Tags: javascript, android

I've used AlarmManager ,so it works every minute 
every minute, service class is called
and it keeps working even after it's turned off 
it's got a sound in the back of the device 
the idea works when i run the app inside Android Studio on device 5.1.1
but i noticed when i disconnected the device from the cable. 
alerts are irregular and audio works 
other times.

```
//
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
         Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), RingAlarm.class);
         PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(),
        12345, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
         AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Activity.ALARM_SERVICE);
         am.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(),
        1 * 60 * 100 , pendingIntent);
    }
}



// --- 
public class RingAlarm extends Service {

    MediaPlayer sound2;

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "الحمد لله", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      sound2 = (MediaPlayer) MediaPlayer.create(RingAlarm.this,R.raw.a2);
      sound2.start();
      return START_STICKY;
    }


    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0){
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
}

// 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.ahmedco.testcode">
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service
            android:name=".RingAlarm" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: is your service keep running how you are stopping alarm can you show code?

Comment: this is Log.e after i remove cable :01-02 11:43:07.762 26397-26397/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
01-02 11:43:07.762 26397-26397/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
01-02 11:43:07.822 741-790/? E/InputDispatcher: channel '10c7ca1a com.ahmedco.testcode/com.ahmedco.testcode.MainActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
01-02 11:43:08.383 855-855/? E/LSO: LSO Service is not yet ready!!!

Comment: too:01-02 11:43:31.735 741-991/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 471 [01-02 11:43:31.742]
01-02 11:43:43.627 24180-24180/? E/MtpServerJNI: server is null in send_object_removed
01-02 11:44:01.735 741-991/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 472 [01-02 11:44:01.743]
01-02 11:44:31.734 741-991/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 473 [01-02 11:44:31.744]